# Getting these errors while ubuntu is booting up

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04, uefi, bios

These errors come during ubuntu boot up, not sure what they mean.
I thought these were due to BIOS but I did my BIOS update after these started coming and they still remain (BIOS update was done from windows, I have a dual boot system).

On the second error screen it takes some time but ubuntu eventually does load after it.

Right now in my laptop I am also encountering another issue wherein it freezes randomly, is it related to that issue?

Specs:

Ubuntu 20.04
Windows 10

Information as required:

```
$ systemd-analyze blame
21.571s plymouth-quit-wait.service                                             >
10.663s gpu-manager.service                                                    >
10.215s gdm.service                                                            >
 6.825s NetworkManager-wait-online.service                                     >
 2.799s dev-nvme0n1p5.device                                                   >
 2.434s snapd.service                                                          >
 1.205s fwupd.service                                                          >
  996ms modprobe@chromeos_pstore.service


$ inxi -GCMm
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: LENOVO product: 81LK v: IdeaPad L340-15IRH Gaming 
  serial: <superuser/root required> 
  Mobo: LENOVO model: LNVNB161216 v: SDK0Q55722 WIN 
  serial: <superuser/root required> UEFI: LENOVO v: BGCN36WW 
  date: 05/24/2022 
Memory:
  RAM: total: 7.67 GiB used: 2.68 GiB (34.9%) 
  RAM Report: 
  permissions: Unable to run dmidecode. Root privileges required. 
CPU:
  Topology: 6-Core model: Intel Core i7-9750HF bits: 64 type: MT MCP 
  L2 cache: 12.0 MiB 
  Speed: 843 MHz min/max: 800/2600 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 900 2: 900 
  3: 900 4: 900 5: 900 6: 900 7: 900 8: 900 9: 900 10: 900 11: 877 12: 1617 
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile / Max-Q] driver: N/A 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.13 driver: fbdev,nouveau 
  unloaded: modesetting,vesa resolution: 1920x1080~77Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 12.0.0 256 bits) v: 4.5 Mesa 21.2.6
```

Putting the error messages in image below into text:

Errors which come right after ubuntu boot-up page:

```
0.281530] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [_SB.PCIO.12C2.T
PDO], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/dswload2-162)
object-220)
0.281538] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name 10okup/catalog (20210730/ps
0.231575] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [_SB.PCIO.12C3.T
PLII, AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/dswload2-162)
[ object-220)
0.231580] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name 1ookup/catalog (20210730/ps
1 T
0.606692] integrity: Problem loading .509 certificate -65 /dev/nvmeon1p5: clean, 547670/6160384 files, 12880490/24616448 blocks
```

After the first screen with error goes away, the second screen has the following messages, and it takes around 20s for it to go away:

```
Starting Dispatcher daemon. for systemd-networkd
[ OK ] Started Set the CPU Frequency Scaling governor.
Starting Authorization Manager...
Starting Restore /etc/resolv.conf if the system crashed before the ppp link was shut down...
Starting System Logging Service...
Starting Secure Boot updates for DB and DBX..
[OK 1 Reached target Login Prompts (Pre).
Starting Snap Daemon...
Starting Switcheroo Control Proxy service...
Starting Login Service...
Starting Thermal Daemon Service...
Starting Disk Manager.
Starting WA supplicant..
Starting Rotate log files...
Starting Daily man-ob regeneration.
OK ] Finished Restore /etc/resolv.conf if the sustem crashed before the ppp link was shut down.
OK J Finished Remove Stale Online ext Metadata Check Snapshots.
Ok ! Started System Logging Service.
[ OK 1 Finished Record successful boot for GRUB.
Starting GRUB failed boot detection...
OK
] Started LSB: automatic crash report generation.
1 Finished GRUB failed boot detection.
1 Finished Secure Boot updates for DB and DBX.
DK
] Started Bluetooth service.
OK I Started Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack.
OK
] Reached target Bluetooth
OK I Started Make remote CUPS printers available locally.
OK
Started MPA supplicant.
] Started Thermal Daemon Service.
OK
] Started Switcheroo Control Proxy service.
Starting Save/Restore Sound Card State...
OK I Finished Save/Restore Sound Card State.
] Reached target Sound Card.
] Started Authorization Manager.
Starting Modem Manager..
Started Network Manager.
Reached target Network.
Starting Network Manager Wait Online..
Starting OpenVPN service..
OK ] Started Service for snap application canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd.
Starting Hostname Service..
Starting Permit User Sessions.
Stopping CUPS Scheduler.
[ OK ] Finished OpenPN service.
OK 1 Finished Permit User Sessions.
Starting Hold until boot process finishes up...
[Ok ] Stopped CUPS Scheduler.
DK
] Started CUPS Scheduler.
] Started Accounts Service.
0
started Disk Manager.
Started Hostname Service.
[ OK 1 Finished Rotate log files.
. 
Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
DK
] Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
D]
] started Modem Manager,
OK
Started Login Service.
] Started Unattended Upgrades Shutdown.
OK 1 Started Dispatcher daemon for systemd-networkd.
Starting Daemon for power management...
OK 1 Started Daemon for power management,
] Finished Dally man-d regeneration.
OK 1 Started Snap Daemon.
Starting Walt unt11 snapd is fully seeded
Starting Time 8. Date Service...
OK 1 started Time & Date Service,
OK
Finished Wait until snapd is fully seeded
```

[image: Error lines]

[image]

Comment: could you share part of your hardware specs: `inxi -GCMm`. Copy the output to your question. In addtion I'd like to see the output from `systemd-analyze blame` (5 lines should suffice)

Comment: Please do not post pictures of text. Cut and paste the text into the body of the question.

Comment: Done the changes , added the output to the following commands and added the text from the images into the body of the question also. Any help would be appreciated thanks!